# pm2 shows 1.2GB while heapdump shows 80MB

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I'm writing a nodeJS application using node v0.12.7.

I'm running my nodejs application using pm2 v0.14.7.

it appears that i have memory leaks in my application since it bounces from around 180MB when I start it to around 1gb afteer 24 hours.

I'm trying to investigate the issue.

so far i found the following tools:

memwatch-next
heapdump
node-inspector

with node-inspector i found some cpu issues and i was able to easily fix them.

with memwatch-next and heapdump i'm trying to get a full map of the application memory, the problem is the following:

after 24 hours of my app running and after pm2 show that the memory increases to more then 1gb, when i create a heapdump using any of these tools, it creates a heapdump of about 80MB.

my question is.. where's the rest ?

if the app memory is around 1GB, how can i see the memory map of my entire application in order to find memory leaks? what am I missing ?

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you use Buffer Object in your code?

> A [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.12.x/api/buffer.html) is similar to an array of integers but corresponds to a raw memory allocation outside the V8 heap

And more，type below code will show

```
process.memoryUsage();
//ouput { rss: 19730432, heapTotal: 9751808, heapUsed: 4768896 }
```

confirm if the value of rss key is equal to pm2's display value;